# Using vector(0) to avoid empty query result creates incorrect graph

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a query that sums up all the results for different labels in such a way:

sum (label=~{"regex"}) +
sum (label=~{"regex"}) +
...

However, some labels have no result and if added as above they return an empty query result instead of 0, invalidating the whole query.

As a workaround I added the following:

sum (label=~{"regex"} or vector(0)) +
sum (label=~{"regex"} or vector(0)) +
...

However, now this gives me a different graph on Grafana and Prometheus than I was expecting. It registers the 0s instead of the actual value.

[Incorrect Grafana Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGP7J.png)

[Incorrect Prometheus Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGzaX.png)

I have a similar Prometheus and Grafana with the same query, however, that returns the right graph for Grafan, even if in the Prometheus it also records the 0s.

[Correct Prometheus Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58CGn.png)

[Correct Grafana Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6QAL.png)

My question is how can I make the first graph become like the 2nd one just registering the actual values instead of these 0 that I'm assuming they come from the use of "or vector(0)" in the query.